# How do I call this function correctly in C++

Tags: c++

I included the code I thought was relevant, I'm not certain how to call the get_data function. I've created instance of the sensor stream class, however can't figure out what to put in the get_data(____)

```
 enum flagState_t
{
    /// Data has been successfully retrieved from the log
    FLAG_DATA_GOOD,
    /// There was an error interpreting the line of data
    FLAG_DATA_LINE_ERROR,
    /// The end of the file has been reached
    FLAG_DATA_FILE_END,
    /// The sensor log file is not open
    FLAG_DATA_FILE_CLOSED
};

float Sensor_Stream::get_data(flagState_t *pFlag)
{
*pFlag = FLAG_DATA_GOOD;
float result = std::nanf("");

if (_mFile.is_open())
{
    std::string str;

    if (std::getline(_mFile, str))
    {
        int lineno;
        int n;

        n = std::sscanf(str.c_str(), "%i, %f", &lineno, &result);

        if (n == 2)
            *pFlag = FLAG_DATA_GOOD;
        else
            *pFlag = FLAG_DATA_LINE_ERROR;
    }
    else
        *pFlag = FLAG_DATA_FILE_END;
}
else
    *pFlag = FLAG_DATA_FILE_CLOSED;

return result;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `stream` is the instance of your class:

```cpp
flagState_t state;
float result = stream.get_data(&state);
```

`get_data` expects a pointer to a flagState_t variable so that it can store the error status in case of failure.
After the call you can check the value of state to see if there's been any error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work, however, I was curious about how I would be able to get all the other pieces of data as well as this only gives the first value.

Comment: What other data? As far as I can tell the function only writes one element

Comment: The code prints a value from a sensor1.csv file which has 2000 elements of data. I think I managed to print all of them by using a while(i < 2000) and i++ loop, the task is to perform a mathematical equation before printing it again.

Comment: I think that looping and calling the function multiple times is the right way, I don't see any other possibility with the function you provided